# Not saving into MySQL database in Java

Tags: java, mysql

I created a form to insert drug information to the db.

Only ItemID, ItemName and Expiry date is required.
User can add other details if want.

My code for above functionality;

```
private void Save_btnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        String id = itemid_txt.getText();
        String name = itemname_txt.getText();
        String rec=reclevel_txt.getText();
        String qty=qty_txt.getText();
        String wp =wprice_txt.getText();
        String sp =sprice_txt.getText();
        Date expp =expday_chooser.getDate();
        String dess = des_txtarea.getText();

        String date = ((JTextField)dayChooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();

        String exp = ((JTextField)expday_chooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
        String des = des_txtarea.getText();

        if(id==null && name==null && exp==null){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fill required fields(Item ID ,Item Name ,Exp Date) and Try again...");

        }else if(wp!=null && sp!=null && rec!=null && qty!=null && exp==null){


            String sql = "Insert into druginfo (ItemID,ItemName,AddedDate,RecorderLevel,InStock,WSPrice,CostPrice,ExpDate,Description)values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

            pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

            pst.setString(1, id);
            pst.setString(2, name);
            pst.setString(3, date);
            pst.setString(4, dess);           
            pst.setString(5, qty);
            pst.setString(6, wp);
            pst.setString(7, sp);
            pst.setString(8, exp);
            pst.setString(9, des);
        }else{
            pst.setString(1, id);
            pst.setString(2, name);
            pst.setString(3, date);
            pst.setString(4, null);           
            pst.setString(5, null);
            pst.setString(6, null);
            pst.setString(7, null);
            pst.setString(8, null);
            pst.setString(9, des);
        }
        pst.execute();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "New Item Data Saved...");

        itemid_txt.setText(null);
        itemname_txt.setText(null);
        reclevel_txt.setText(null);
        qty_txt.setText(null);        
        wprice_txt.setText(null);
        sprice_txt.setText(null);
        expday_chooser.setDate(null);
        des_txtarea.setText(null);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(InventoryManagementenew.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }



}
```

But not adding to the database when only required fields given and all fields are are given. Code throws `java.lang.NullPointerException` .

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.bit.project.InventoryManagementenew.Save_btnActionPerformed(InventoryManagementenew.java:468)
at com.bit.project.InventoryManagementenew.access$500(InventoryManagementenew.java:27)
at com.bit.project.InventoryManagementenew$6.actionPerformed(InventoryManagementenew.java:366)
```

line 468 is `pst.setString(1, id);`.

Help me to correct this.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only initialize the `PreparedStatement` in the `else if` clause. The `else` part has neither the sql string nor the prepared statement.

Answer (score 2):

State `pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);` before your `if-else` conditions currently it will only be initialized in first `else if` part otherwise `pst` will be `null` in subsequent `else-if` and `else` block.

Answer (score 2):

Your preparedStatement object is referring to null as it is only initialized in if block of if-else-if construct. 
To solve the problem either initialize the preparedStatement outside if-else-if block or initialize it in each block if, elseif and else. 
One thing more you are not closing preparedStatement in your code this could lead to memory leak and will cause out of memory or too many connections to DB at higher rate of transactions in future.